# input type hidden value into the django template filters

Tags: html, django, django-template-filters

I want to use one custom django filter.
It is having 2 variable movpath and projectname.
movpath is coming from input type hidden.

```
{% if movpath|is_path_exist:projectName %}
     do something
{% else %}
     do something
{% endif %}
```

Is it possible that we can take input type hidden value into the django template.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of using templates in Django consists in passing [context variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) to it. Consequently

So, at some point, you should have

```
context = {'form': form}, 'movpath': movpath}
render("template_name.html", context)
```

where `movpath` is obtained from the form's hidden field.

This way, the value of the hidden field of the form is passed to the context, which is passed to the template during rendering.